# Script that shuffle data in table variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I was tasked to solve this but I have been battling with it for days now. can anyone help to solve it ?

1, write the T-SQL to insert the following values into a table variable, which has an identity column, 5 address lines and a postcode column:

```
-- address line 1: 'Churchill house'
-- address line 2: ' '
-- address line 3: '30 Boston Road'
-- address line 4: ' '
-- address line 5: 'lusaka'
-- postcode: 'e12 3re'
```

2, write a script to shuffle up the address lines in the table variable from Question 1

```
-- address line 1: 'Churchill house'
-- address line 2: ' '
-- address line 3: '30 Boston Road'
-- address line 4: ' '
-- address line 5: 'lusaka'
-- postcode: 'e12 3re'
```

Comment: First show what you did, and why it didn't work. Otherwise people might just be wasting their time telling you things that you've already ruled out. Or they might think you haven't actually tried anything, and not reply! It helps to show that you've actually tried something before getting others to write it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part is pretty straight forward:

```
declare @t table (
    id int identity(1,1)
  , address_line_1 varchar(64)
  , address_line_2 varchar(64)
  , address_line_3 varchar(64)
  , address_line_4 varchar(64)
  , address_line_5 varchar(64)
  , postal_code varchar(64)
);

insert into @t values ('Churchill house','','30 Boston Road','','lusaka','e12 3re')

select * from @t
```

returns:

```
+----+-----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+-------------+
| id | address_line_1  | address_line_2 | address_line_3 | address_line_4 | address_line_5 | postal_code |
+----+-----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+-------------+
|  1 | Churchill house |                | 30 Boston Road |                | lusaka         | e12 3re     |
+----+-----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+-------------+
```

---

depending on how you define "shuffle", this may be sufficient:

```
update @t
set address_line_1 = address_line_2
  , address_line_2 = address_line_3
  , address_line_3 = address_line_4
  , address_line_4 = address_line_5
  , address_line_5 = address_line_1

select * from @t
```

returns:

```
+----+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+-------------+
| id | address_line_1 | address_line_2 | address_line_3 | address_line_4 | address_line_5  | postal_code |
+----+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+-------------+
|  1 |                | 30 Boston Road |                | lusaka         | Churchill house | e12 3re     |
+----+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+-------------+
```

---

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/WLPAMZ69008